# Create a list view in a subfolder using the job DSL plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

In Jenkins you can easily create a list view with the Job DSL

```
listView("myView") {
    jobs {
        regex(".*")
    }
}
```

but if you try to create a list view within a folder, the folder will be created but not the view

```
folder("someFolder")

listView("someFolder/myView") {
    jobs {
        regex(".*")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your DSL script is correct and works for me. Do you see any errors in the seed job's console output or the Jenkins log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs when a Job DSL performs operations in this order:

1. Create a folder
2. Create a view for that folder
3. Re-create the folder

The reason this happens is that views live in the config file for a folder. When you re-generate a folder, it deletes any configured views for that folder.

To fix this issue in my case, I removed any duplicate folder creation so that each folder was only created once.

Answer (score -2):

Please use a relative path to create Jobs or pipeline;

```
jobDsl lookupStrategy: 'SEED_JOB',
    targets: ['src/jobs/**/*.groovy'].join('\n')
```

1. Create a folder
2. Create seed job pipeline in folder
3. The seed jobs name does not contain the name of the directory